# How to use RDC with VirtualBox and OSX

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I'm trying to do some local RDC testing using VirtualBox.  The host is OSX.8, the VM is ubuntu, and VirtualBox is version 4.1.22.

The VM starts fine without any problems.  I shut it down and choose "Enable Server" from the Remote Display section of the Display options and start again, and again it starts fine. Note that the port is left default and the authentication is "null".

I start Microsoft's RDC (v2.1.0) and type in 'localhost' and get: You were disconnected from the Windows-based computer because of network problems.

I try 127.0.0.1 and get the same error.  Then I type in the IP of my (host) computer and get the same error.  I know the loopback address avoids the firewall but I turned it off anyway and got the same error.

I get the same error whether I'm using NAT networking or bridged.  What am I doing wrong?

I should note that this is a vanilla install of VirtualBox and I haven't added any extensions or guest additions or anything like that.

Seems I'm doing everything right.  What am I missing? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Problem Solved! You have to install the "VirtualBox 4.1.22 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack" (available on the VB download page) to make RDC work.  I wish it would tell you this when you click "enable server" but I guess that's asking too much.  I hope this helps someone else.